# PureOS Command Line Window

Tags: command, window, pureos, line

I'm new to PureOS and I've been looking for a way to open a command line window without any luck. How do I open a console/command line window in PureOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following (I usually do this when I don't have a mouse):

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
- then type **`gnome-terminal`** and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

The other thing that should work under normal conditions is to:

- press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key (usually located between the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys on the left side of a U.S. keyboard
- then type `gnome-terminal` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you would prefer not to launch `gnome-terminal`, you can perform any of the above with `xterm` or another terminal window of your choosing, assuming it is already installed